# Ajax call inside @onchange throws error "url undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to call Ajax to fill the dripdown when user changes the parent dropdown , but im getting url undefined error , Can any one guide me please

Thanks in Advance.

.cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownList("queueclientDropdownList", new SelectList(Model.Clients, "Id", "Name"), "Select Client", new { ng_model = "queueclientDropdownList", ng_required = "false", ng_value = "false", @class = "form-control", @onchange = "ClientChange()" })
```

Ajax Call:

```
function ClientChange() {
    var clientId = $('#queueclientDropdownList').val();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/QueueBuilder/GetDepartmentsByClient',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "JSON",
        data: { clientId: clientId },
        success: function (data) {
            $("#queuedepartmentDropdownList").empty();
            $("#queuedepartmentDropdownList").append($('<option></option>').val(0).html("Select Department"));
            $.each(data, function (i, department) {
                $("#queuedepartmentDropdownList").append($('<option></option>').val(department.Id).html(department.Name));
            });
        }
    });
    return true;
}
```

Comment: That's an odd error. Do you have a variable named `url` somewhere? Are you sure the error is not 'function not defined'? Also, you appear to be using Angular so I'd strongly suggest you attach your events through that instead of using outdated `on*` event attributes, and also use it for the AJAX request as you shouldn't really be using jQuery and Angular together.

Comment: Did you try `@Url.Action("GetDepartmentsByClient", "QueueBuilder")` in `url` part? Are you trying to call a method that outside of controller class? Since variable named `url` not used anywhere, you need to check both request and response details in browser's debugger (i.e. 'network' tab).

Comment: don't build your URLs by hand, use Url.Action as suggested by Tetsuya. Otherwise there's a good chance you'll get it wrong. Plus, if your routes change for any reason then using Url.Action means MVC will handle this automatically.

Answer (score -1):

Please try to change your url parameter to :

```
url: 'your_project_baseurl/controller/method/function_name',
```

Comment: Thanks all, I solved by getting SiteRoot like var url =  document.page.Siteroot;